# ubuntu theme error i can't update ubuntu

Tags: package-management, themes

I have ubuntu 16.04 i install max os theme

this link http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/macbuntu-1604-transformation-pack-for.html

the problem is when i typed apt-get update, i got this message

so i delete theme files following the link

what should i do to remove this message? it's too slow also i can't do software update and source code update.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**this is part of apt-get update result**

root@found:~# apt-get update
Hit:

```
1 http://ftp.neowiz.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ftp.neowiz.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                    
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/macbuntu/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
Hit:4 http://ftp.neowiz.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                  
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/themes/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
Hit:7 http://ftp.neowiz.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease            
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/vidplace7/bluez5/ubuntu xenial 
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/vidplace7/bluez5/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/vidplace7/bluez5/ubuntu xenial/main 
Ign:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/vidplace7/bluez5/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/themes/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/vidplace7/bluez5/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/themes/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/vidplace7/bluez5/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned that you have followed the instructions in that [link](http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/macbuntu-1604-transformation-pack-for.html). So you will need to revert this step:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
```

Just run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
```

Replace that `ppa:noobslab/macbuntu` with whatever you've added before.

Also, I noticed that it's not the noobslab ppa that's causing this issue. The error (those message start with **E:**) indicates the problem lies within upubuntu-com and vidplace ppa, you might want to remove them as well

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:upubuntu-com/gtk3
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:upubuntu-com/themes
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:vidplace7/bluz5
```

When you're done, try `sudo apt-get update` again.

Comment: ubuntu and ubuntu xenial is different?

Comment: Answer could be yes and no, I would like to know why you are asking this first?

Comment: sorry it's my fault

Comment: commands perfectly works . after apt-get update :                                                                   Hit:1 http://ftp.neowiz.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease....................                          _______________________________________________                                                                                                                                            i think before install theme that there's no message like xenial. so i want to ask to you.

Comment: OK! The problem is that for those non-working ppa, they are available for other Ubuntu distros but not for Xenial, let's take the [upubuntu-com/gtk3 ppa](http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3/ubuntu/dists/) for example, it's only available for distros before Raring (you can check other ppa, just copy the http address till dists/ in the error message) Before you try to install the theme, you should still see "xenial" in the `apt-get update` output, as you're running on Xenial. Hope this helps.